# Narrow-bandwidth laser and its beam size on uncertainty principle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics, laser, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

I read that a single frequency laser can have a bandwidth as low as a few kHz, but according to the uncertainty principle, $\Delta x \Delta p = \Delta x \Delta f h/c >=\hbar $, so  $\Delta x  \sim c/\Delta f$, how come the laser beam can be so narrow spatially?

Comment: Just to add to Gilbert's answer in other words. The $\Delta x$ means it is in the direction the laser is "travelling". What this bandwidth means, it means that there is still a perfect phase relation between your location and several km down- or up-stream of the laser, or conversely, you can wait until those parts reach you, so several milliseconds. Like he said, the laser spot (transversely) has to do with diffraction. The difference between putting photons "side by side" and their actual propagation direction, ie frequency/wavelength.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $\Delta x$ relevant for your calculation is the *longitudinal* length of the wave. If you have a narrow bandwidth, then you need a lot of wave cycles to define it, and so the wave is long.

The *transverse* width of a laser beam is limited by diffraction.

Comment: I think the question really is in a laser that occupies a few $cm^3$ volume *what thing* has $300\times 10^6/10^3=300km$ *physical length* so the radiation has 1kHz coherence bandwidth?

Comment: @hyportnex are you asking for yourself (in which case I may answer in a comment), or are you suggesting that I expand the above answer?

Comment: please, expand your answer